# Store python zipapp (`.pyz`) on PyPi Nexus

Tags: python, nexus, pypi, zipapp

I use Python [zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html) (more precisely [shiv](https://github.com/linkedin/shiv)) to ship Python module.

I would like to store generated zipapp (`.pyz`) on Nexus (ideally `pypi` on Nexus) to keep track of my built artifact in a CI/CD pipeline.

How can I upload `.pyz` on Nexus?

Is it possible to store it in hosted `pypi` on Nexus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up by pushing the `.pyz` artifact in a `maven` repository on `Nexus`. It seems to work pretty well by pushing the artifact with a simple `curl`:

```sh
curl -v -u NEXUS_USER:NEXUS_PASSWORD \
   --upload-file artifact.pyz \ 
   NEXUS_URL/repository/my_repo/artifact.pyz
```